# Google Analytics API: Find out if user has associated Analytics account

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

Does anybody have any success with retreving the count of analytics account associated with google account.

I am referring to this page

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list

Here the `Try it` widget at the bottom throws the following when there is no analytics account associated:

```
403 Forbidden

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "User does not have any Google Analytics account."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User does not have any Google Analytics account."
 }
}
```

In order to avoid getting this exception, I want to retrieve the count before I execute this API call

`analytics_service.management().accounts().list().size()`

However, it always returns zero irrespective the Google account has Analytics accounts associated with it or not.

Any ideas where I am going wrong.

Comment: check and see if there is a property in the API for totalResults.

Comment: You might want to verify that there is actually a Google Analytics account associated with the Google account you're authorizing access to. As per the error message, you're getting the response for an account with no Google Analytics, which basically indicates a size of 0.